# modal('show') is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i made a function appendScript which will be called on a button click event my function code is

```
function appendScript() {
    var v_js;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    v_js = document.createElement('script');
    v_js.type = 'text/javascript';
    v_js.src = "/resource/1372205606000/jquery_min_js";
    head.appendChild(v_js);
    interval = self.setInterval(function () { 
        if (jQuery) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);

            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            v_js = document.createElement('script');
            v_js.type = "text/javascript";

            v_js.src = "/resource/1372176744000/bootstrap_min_js";
        }  
        body.appendChild(v_js);
        var v_css = document.createElement('link'); 
        v_css.rel = "stylesheets";
        v_css.type = "text/css";
        v_css.href = "/resource/1372206945000/bootstrap_min_css";
        body.appendChild(v_css);  
    }, 300);

    var interval1  = self.setInterval(  function () {  

        if (typeof (jQuery.fn.modal) !== 'undefined')    {
            console.log('Hello!!'); 
            window.clearInterval(interval1);
            jQuery(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).append('<div id="myModal"  class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"   aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p>One fine body…</p></div><div  class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button><button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>');

            jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

this code is not showing modal when i click on the button. Can anyone please help why its not showing Modal dialogue, when i am calling modal function with show parameter ? its showing Hello!! in console and adding these elements properly but the only line that is not working as expected is below.

```
jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Just as a note/suggestion, you don't need to use `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` - just use `document.body`

Comment: Please indent your code properly, that's a one big mess now.

Comment: @Teemu Just fixed, I was having problems too

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot. Though OP could have done it himself ; ).

Comment: @Ian ok i will change this in my code

Comment: @Teemu Oh I know, I was just already in the process. I'm already in the habit of doing it quickly, so I thought I'd just help them out :)

Comment: @Teemu sorry for poor indentation i will keep this in my mind in future !!

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta Also, another suggestion - some browsers have support for `document.head`, so you could use: `var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but please reply to original question why its not showing modal .i stuck badly .

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta And instead of dealing with `setInterval`/`clearInterval`, you could access the script's `onload` property to know when the script has loaded. For example, you use `var script = document.createElement("script"); script.onload = function () { /* YOUR CODE */ }; script.src = "whatever URL";`

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta I know. I can't see an immediate problem, but I'm noticing other things that I'm suggesting. It's the best I can do for now, I'll keep looking

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32375/discussion-between-ritesh-mehandiratta-and-ian)

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta Did you end up getting this working?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423995/bootstrap-3-showing-modal-doesnt-work-with-the-javascript-way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the original problem was, but something I noticed was setting the `rel` property of the dynamic `<link>` was using "stylesheets", when it should be "stylesheet". Both that, and using the `onload` method of loading things, I got it working:

```
function appendScript() {
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        $script;
    if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
        $script = document.createElement('script');
        $script.type = 'text/javascript';
        $script.onload = jQueryLoaded;
        $script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js";
        head.appendChild($script);
    } else {
        jQueryLoaded();
    }
}

function jQueryLoaded() {
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        linkTB = document.createElement('link'),
        scriptTB = document.createElement('script');

    if (typeof jQuery.fn.modal === "undefined") {
        linkTB.rel = "stylesheet";
        linkTB.type = "text/css";
        linkTB.href = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";
        head.appendChild(linkTB); 

        scriptTB.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptTB.onload = twitterBSLoaded;
        scriptTB.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js";
        head.appendChild(scriptTB);
    } else {
        twitterBSLoaded();
    }
}

function twitterBSLoaded() {
    jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="myModal"  class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"   aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p>One fine body…</p></div><div  class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button><button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>');
    jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hz3Bw/1/

Of course, this uses CDN files, so the URLs have been changed so it works in the jsFiddle.