# Bootstrap 3 / showing modal doesn't work with the javascript way

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use the [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) feature from Bootstrap 3.0.

I have this code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/myNestedContent" data-target="#myModal">
  Open the modal containing the content
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
//nested content will be inserted here
</div>
```

When I click on the anchor (the link), the whole works => I see the modal with the content.

However, when I use the Javascript way (instead of the link) to show the modal like this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

I only see the fade effect without the modal being shown...

**When I started by clicking on the link, THEN calling the javascript, it works. (side effect?)**

**When I started by the javascript way, EVEN the link only shows the fade effect without the modal.**

Might it be .. a bug from the `modal` Javascript method?

For information, the declarations of my scripts that I use are in the right order:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.form.min.js"></script> 
<script src="javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but it works for me using the method you described - http://jsfiddle.net/kZyLu/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i am not sure if i have misunderstood your question.

According to my understanding of your question, you need

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    show: true,
    remote: '/myNestedContent'
});
```

you cannot just

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

because there is no url provided in this js method.

does this solve your question?

Comment: I haven't tested yet that I did a +1 since it sounds pretty obvious. :). Indeed, currently, my remote path declaration is only present with the link way.  Shame on me ? :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Readers should note that the "remote:" option is being deprecated - see answer below

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is **remove** the **data-target** from the **html tag** when used with js, leaving it call twice the function then one shows it and the other removes it. Thats how i solved.

Answer (score 0):

Readers should note that the "remote:" option is being deprecated...  [per the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

"This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and will be removed in v4. We recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.

If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-content div. If you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown below:"

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```